# Disable Java making big number smaller? (10,000,000,000 to 1E10)

Tags: java, integer

I have a big number in a database; in this case, 10,000,000,000. Whenever I use that information for something, like sending a message with it, instead of 10,000,000,000, it says 1E10, and I really do not want that.

Can I avoid that in any way?

If I go to the database, the value is 10,000,000,000.

Comment: Store it as a string instead.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html

Comment: Can you add the code where you are storing the value? Specifically the type you are using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the *same* number, just represented in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Since you don't describe how you are storing the value, you can use [`DecimalFormat#getNumberInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getIntegerInstance()) to help format it to one that doesn't contain the scientific notation.

```
double foo = 10000000000L;
System.out.println(foo);
System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(foo));
```

This outputs:

```
1.0E10
10,000,000,000
```